# stop animated slides from stacking

Tags: javascript, angular

I was following the Angular2 [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) to animate my slideshow, but ran into the problem of slides stacking on each other instead of sliding across the same row. I am using `void => *` and `* => void` to get the slides to pan in and pan out in response to the click event.

```
@Component({
//metadata...
  animations: [
  trigger('flyOut', [
    transition('void => *', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
      animate(700)
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(700, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
    ])
  ])
] 
})
```

The issue is that the new slide pushes the old slide down as the animation happens; so the old slide ends up below the new slide as it crosses the screen. I thought this might be a styling problem, so i changed the template div containing the slide to `display: inline-block`. However, this didn't resolve the issue. I would really appreciate any help.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PKDH9tDLHnjrK4flyK1A?p=preview